# C# Seeding JObject to database with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, optimization, translation

Context:
I am building a web app (asp .net c#) That must store a few user submitted translations in the database using Entity Framework 6. The other translations are constants from a .json file on the server which works fine, so the question is about a small part (10%) of the app translation that must be configurable by the administrator. A good example of this dynamic user translation would be : A translatable blog posted by another user.

The problem:
To me it makes sense to store a translation together with a blog post in the database. This could require something like a Dictionary or Json like property (50+ languages) for the blog model. When I try to seed a JObject (converted to string) it is not written to the database.

```
protected override void Seed(AppDbContext context)
    {
      List<SectionModel> sections = new List<SectionModel>
      {
        new SectionModel() { Test = JObject.FromObject(new { en = "To do" }) },
      };
    
      context.Sections.AddRange(sections);
    
      context.SaveChanges();
      base.Seed(context);
    }
```

The next time I start the web app and try to retrieve seeded data results in this error:

System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: 'One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

App.DBContext.JToken: : EntityType 'JToken' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
JTokens: EntityType: EntitySet 'JTokens' is based on type 'JToken' that has no keys defined.
'

JToken appeared and today disappeared out of nowhere, that seems solved.

The model I use looks like this:

```
 public class SectionModel
    {
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int Id { get; set; }
    
      public string Title { get; set; }
    
      [Column("Test")]
      private string _test;
      [NotMapped]
      public JObject Test
      {
        get
        {
          return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_test) ? "{}" : _test);
        }
        set
        {
          _test = value.ToString();
        }
      }
    }
```

To read the DB I use SQL Server management studio.
I had expected the property Test to appear as stringified Json, instead nothing is written to DB.

Question summary, using blog example:
What is the best way to store multiple translation strings for a blog model in DB using Entity Framework? (Preferably using a format similar to Dictionary or Json within that blog to keep it all clean?) Why can't I get the stringified JObject into the DB the way I try to store it in the example?

Comment: Just to make sure, is there any `context.SaveChanges()` in your code ? it won't save any changes unless you have that, but I suppose this is not the problem

Comment: I wasn't cause I didn't know it was necessary when seeding, I tried :
<pre>
<code>
      context.SaveChanges();
      base.Seed(context);
      context.SaveChanges();
</code>
</pre>
To be sure, but I still get the same error. I noticed the DB isnt being regenerated at all. I tried  
context.Database.Initialize(force: true);
 for that. Whenever I build and launch my web app I get the above 'JToken' has no key defined error

Comment: What you are trying to do is far from being "normal". First of all, something is not clear : what is your approach ? db first or code first ? Your add code is ok, but you have to look into your db, what is Title ? Nvarchar(4000) ? If this is the case, then nothing should be placed here other than a pure string type

Comment: My approach is code first. I try to store json as a string. At the moment any getting or saving operation to the database fails with error "App.DBContext.JToken: : EntityType 'JToken' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType." The database is not being created anymore by EF since deletion. Before I removed the DB everything except saving of this title field worked fine

Comment: I did some cleanup on the original post as the JToken error solved itself out of nowhere. DB regenerates again as well.
I renamed property Title to Test (I thought maybe It's some EF convention thing as the name so generic) and some small cleanup in the code.. Remaining issue is the "Test" Property is not being written to DB, which sets as string and gets as JObject

Comment: Again... this is not "normal". But is it really a limitation of EF ? Or is it just the size of the data recorded greater than what your db can actually store ? Honestly the code you have provided should work... except for the fact that you specified that "Test" is not mapped... And I think it should be mapped because you want it to be saved in the database

Comment: it's a few strings per language max, tested like : { "en": "First Translation" }. adding another model for translation only seems overkill but maybe that's normal. 
I'm going to test a bit with the model, if I figure it out myself I will post the solution here :). I'm new with entity framework so maybe I'm not seeing something. I tried excluding mapping of the public property because it's a JObject, and including the private property (converted to string) instead but that didn't work. In the meantime I had to complete some other parts of the system so I will continue research today.